# How to wire proxy objects in spring?

Tags: java, spring, rmi

I am using proxy beans with property-selectable transport protocol. My problem is that bean properties cannot be converted, but I really don't know why. This is the situation:

My property: service.protocol=rmi

```
<!-- This is the 'multiplexing' factory bean (using this because properties
cannot be used in bean names and aliases -->

   <bean name="dbFormGenWindowComponent" 
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanReferenceFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetBeanName" value="dbFormGenWindowComponent-${service.protocol}invoker" />
 </bean>

<!-- Here are the service invoker beans with two protocols: -->

  <bean name="dbFormGenWindowComponent-rmiinvoker" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
 <property name="serviceUrl" value="${ringwindow.serviceURL.rmi}/${ringwindow.service.name}-dbFormGenWindowComponent"/>
 <property name="serviceInterface" value="foo.bar.service.formgen.windows.FormGenWindowComponent" />
 <property name="lookupStubOnStartup" value="false"/>
  </bean>
```

The exception on startup is:

> org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException:
>   Failed to convert property value of
>   type [$Proxy541] to required type
>   [foo.bar.service.formgen.windows.FormGenWindowComponent]
>   for property 'formGenWindowComponent';
>   nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Cannot convert value of type
>   [$Proxy541] to required type
>   [foo.bar.service.formgen.windows.FormGenWindowComponent]
>   for property 'formGenWindowComponent':
>   no matching editors or conversion
>   strategy found

I think nested factory beans should work fine. Do you have any idea how to get this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens when you have defined your injection point types to be concrete classes, rather than interfaces, but you are proxying based on interface. For example:

```
public interface Foo { .. }
public class FooImpl { .. } // this is declared as bean

public class Bar {
    private FooImpl foo; // this fails
    private Foo foo; // correct way
}
```

In the case of factory beans this may be due to the factory bean's return type being defined as a concrete class. If you can't change anything in the classes, you can configure spring to use cglib-proxying, by:

- `<aop:scoped-proxy>` - inside a bean definition - this will configure proxies of the bean
- `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true">` - changes this globally

Comment: I checked the thing that you mentioned, my proxyies are that of interfaces and the beans they are plugged in also declare their getters/setters for the interfaces.. However while examining this I figured out that all my BeanReferenceFactoryBeans were pointing to the same proxy, this was the real problem. I should have noticed that all the ClassCastExceptions complained about the very same numbered proxy object.. :-( Thanks for your kind help Bozho!